# I want to update sqlalchemy but getting error

Tags: python, sql-update, flask-sqlalchemy

trying to update an object from my db but getting error or nothing happen this is my update func:

```
@views.route("/update/<int:id>" , methods = [ "GET" , "POST"])
@login_required
def update(id):
   bars = Barname.query.get_or_404(id)  #1
   if request.method == "POST" :
      try:
        bars.data= request.form["sender"]  #2
        db.session.commit()
        flash ("updated successfully" , category = "success")
        return render_template("home.html" , user = current_user )
      except :
        flash ("something went wrong" , category = "error")
        return render_template("home.html" , user = current_user)
   else :
    return render_template("update.html" , user = current_user , bars=bars )
```

my GET request send me to the update.html and POST request should update the object, after completing the form and submit it it pops off the "updated successfully " but doesn't commit it to db , I tried to change the location of #1 and move it before "try" and after "try" and also after else statement but either get an error or "except" execute also I changed #2 to `request.form.get("sender")` but also didn't work the problem is even if `db.session.commit()` execute it doesn't change the db. idk if it's necessary but this is my home.html and update.html maybe there is something wrong with them(!!!):

```
{% extends "base.html" %} {% block title %}{{bars.data}}{% endblock %}{% block  content  %}
   
    <div class="form">
        <form action="/update/{{bars.id}}" method = "POST" >
             <input type="text" name = "sender" id = "sender"  placeholder="{{bars.data}}" ><br/><br/>
            <div align = "center">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="update" >  
              </div>
        </form>
        </div>
{% endblock %}
```

home.html:

```
<ul class = "list-group list-group-flush" id = "notes">

{% for bars in user.barnames  %}
  <li class = "list-group-item">
       <h1 name="barnameId" id="barnameId" >  {{ bars.data }} </h1>
       
         <div align="right">
             <a href="/delete/{{bars.id}}">
             <input type = "button" class="btn btn-primary" value="delete" ></a>
        
              <a href="/update/{{bars.id}}" method="POST">
              <input type="button" class = "btn btn-primary" value="update" > </a>   
             
         </div>    
       
    </li>
{% endfor %}    
   
</ul>
```

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71626622/5320906) may help you to debug the problem.

Comment: @snakecharmerb thank you sir i found my answer i have to write 'bars = db.session.merge(bars)' before #2

Comment: It seems strange that `bars` is not already in the session.